# Python 2: how to pass arguments in tuple to a function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, functional-programming, python-2.x

I would like to pass a tuple of arguments `args` (at what the tuple varies in length due to some other functions) to a function, which works

```
def myf(x1,x2,x3,....)
    return something involving x1,x2....

args = (y1,y2,.....)

call myf with args as myf(y1,y2,....)
```

How do you achieved this? In my actual problem I am working with `sympy` the the function `myf` is actually `reshape` and the variable argument list `args` is a tuple generated by getting the shape of some n-d-array, say `A`, so `args = A.shape`. In the end I want to reshape another array `B` based on the shape of `A`. A minimal example ist

```
from sympy import *
A = Array(symbols('a:2:3:4:2'),(2,3,4,2))
B = Array(symbols('b:8:3:2'),(8,3,2))
args = A.shape
print args
print B.reshape(2,3,4,2) # reshape(2,3,4,2) is the correct way to call it
print B.reshape(args) # This is naturally wrong since reshape((2,3,4,2)) is not the correct way to call reshape
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use argument unpacking:

```
def myf(x1,x2,x3):
    return x1 + x2 + x3

args = (1, 2, 3)

myf(*args)  # 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to unpack the tuple:

```
B.reshape(*args)
```